# How do I get a product key for Visual Studio Express Desktop 2012 if I am not a business?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, registration, product-key

I have been using VS Express 2012 for almost a month and now it states that I must enter a product key to continue using it. To get that product key I am asked to register. Only after creating a Microsoft account (great, another account to keep track of) does it inform me that I must enter details about my company, its address, its employees, and my role in it.
Is there a way for individuals or hobbyists to use Express or is it intended for businesses only? Is there any way to get a product key without entering fake business information (or is fake information the standard response to frustrating forms)?

Comment: That is not express that's a trial of VS2012.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `You can use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop to build powerful desktop apps in C#, Visual Basic, and C++. [...] After installation, you can try this product for up to 30 days. You must register to obtain a free product key for ongoing use after 30 days.` http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express

Comment: While it seems inappropriate that the form requires business information, it also seems like there are several ways to fill that information out that is accurate.  "Self", "Not Applicable", etc.  Is there a programming related question here that I'm missing?

Comment: There isn't a question that relates to code or anything. I was just trying to program and ran into this VS problem and thought that on a site full of programmers somebody else might have encountered this problem.
I didn't find anything too helpful on google or microsoft sites.
Is this not a SO appropriate question?

Comment: I looked at the FAQ. It is a question about programming tools. I think it is a perfectly valid SO question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Changed the rules again have they? Ho hum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop (or any other flavor) is distributed free of charge. It is not intended for businesses only. Go ahead and register it and use it.

Now as for what to enter, I try to be as truthful as possible on forms that ask questions that there isn't a good answer for. In general:

- Business Name: My name (or sometimes N/A)
- Business Address: My home address
- Employees: 1
- My role: Sole Employee